# Tikzcd: set description option in labels of arrows as default

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd, optional-arguments

I want all arrows in my tikzcd diagrams to have labels over them, as in the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[sep = large]
T
\arrow[drr, bend left, "x" description]
\arrow[ddr, bend right, "y" description] 
\arrow[dr, dotted, "{(x,y)}" description] & & \\
& X \times_Z Y \arrow[r, "p" description] \arrow[d, "q" description] & X 
\arrow[d, "f" description] \\ 
& Y \arrow[r, "g" description] & Z 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

But I don't want to write all those ‘description’s. Is it possible to set an option to the tikzcd environment that makes it default? Is it also possible to have an option for \arrow that restores the usual behaviour for that arrow?

Answer (score 3):

Use `labels=description`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[sep = large,labels=description]
T
\arrow[drr, bend left, "x"]
\arrow[ddr, bend right, "y"]
\arrow[dr, dotted, "{(x,y)}"] & & \\
& X \times_Z Y \arrow[r, "p"] \arrow[d, "q"] & X
\arrow[d, "f"] \\
& Y \arrow[r, "g"] & Z
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]